# How do I add in constraint into a create table statement?

Tags: sql, constraints, create-table

If I had a create table statement like this in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Garage
(
    vinID integer,
    make varchar(20),
    year integer,
    model varchar(20),
    registrationID integer,
    Primary Key (vinID)
);
```

How would I add a constraint stating that every car should be year should be at least 5 years old?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Do you want 2014 cars to be allowed next year?

Comment: @jarlh I'm not using one just trying out some practice, but cars have to be at least from 2013.

Comment: Are you using DB2?

Comment: Add `constraint at_least_5_years check (year <= 2013)` somewhere. Add a comma too.

Comment: @uSeruSher Nope no servers, just writing this on a blank sql file

Comment: Read about "Check Constraints" you will get an idea :)